# Does ServiceStack's OrmLite support nested transactions? If so, how?

Tags: c#, transactions, ormlite-servicestack

I'm looking for a working example of an outer method containing a transaction calling an inner method which also contains a transaction.  Typically, this sort of thing is managed using a TransactionScope, but that doesn't seem to work with ServiceStack's OrmLite.

To be clear, I'm not looking for how to set up a transaction.  I'm looking for how to set up nested transactions such that the innermost transactions *enlist* in the outermost transaction using OrmLite.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but it's something that I've stumbled across. My answer is only related to SqlServer so may differ depending on the provider.

You can't have 2 transactions on the same connection. If you try to open multiple transactions you will get an `InvalidOperationException: SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions.`

You can have nested transactions from different connections:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
using (var tran = db.OpenTransaction())
{
  // operations on db...
  using (var nestedDb = dbFactory.Open())
  using (var nestedTran = nestedDb.OpenTransaction())
  { // .Rollback/.Commit as required }
}
```

Using the above if you call `nestedTran.Commit()` and `tran.Rollback()` then the changes made within nestedTran will be persisted despite the outer transaction being rolled-back.

However, I've done a quick test using `TransactionScope` and it is working fine with OrmLite.SqlServer.